# manejo de memoria

Tags: java, optimización

¿Qué es mas costoso en cuanto a uso de memoria: crear un objeto de una clase, usarlo y, después de que no se ocupa, igualarlo a `null`; o mantenerlo abierto durante todo el proceso?.

Ejemplo:

```
public class Conexiones {
    private Connection objConnectionVentas = null;
    private Connection objConnectionClientes = null;
    private Connection objConnectionProveedores = null;
    private Connection objConnectionProductos = null;
    private Connection objConnectionTiendas = null;

public void close()
{
   objConnectionVentas.close();
   cerrar los demas objetos...
}
get....
set....
}

//uso de la clase Conexiones 
clase VentasBO()
{
   Conexiones conn;

   public void Ventas()
   {
      conn = new Conexiones;
   }
   
   public Cliente buscarcliente(int id)
   {

     //realizar una busqueda de clientes utilizando el objeto conn
     CLienteDal cte = new CLienteDal(conn);
   }
   public void finalizarVentas
   {
     //finalizar la venta utilizando el objeto conn
     VentasDal vnt = new VentasDal(conn);
   }
   
   etc...
}
```

En este ejemplo, tenemos una clase `ClienteDal` que recibe como parámetro una instancia de la clase `Conexiones` y se encarga de buscar, registrar y modificar clientes, tenemos otra clase que se llama `VentasDal` que también recibe como parámetro creamos una instancia de la clase `Conexiones` y se encarga de guardar y buscar, el objeto `conn` lo mantenemos durante todo el proceso, la otra opción es crear una conexión en cada una de las clases (`ClienteDal`, `VentasDal`) y cerrarlas allí mismo.

Comment: Asignarlo a null no hace que se borre directamente. Lo hace la GC cuando lo crea oportuno.

Answer (score 5):

Ya que tu pregunta abarca solamente el aspecto **memoria** del programa, se puede responder sin lugar a dudas que, desde ese punto de vista, lo mejor es crear un objeto, utilizarlo y luego liberarlo —cosa que en *java* sabemos de antemano que podemos hacer solo de manera indirecta— ya sea asignando `null` a la referencia del objeto o bien dejando que sus referencias salgan de contexto.

Por poner un ejemplo, en el hipotético caso de una conexión, podríamos utilizar una variable local, a la cual no tenemos que asignar `null`al final, pues saldrá de contexto al terminar el método y, con eso, el *recolector de basura* se encargará de ella en su momento; algo en la línea de:

```
public Cliente buscarCliente(int id)
{
   Conexion conn;
   localConn = new Conexion();
   CLiente result = realmenteBuscarAlCliente(localConn, id);
   return result;
   //acá, al terminar el método, la variable localConn sale de 
   //contexto y eventualmente será destruida, liberando la memoria que ocupa.
}
```

O bien, asignar `null` explicitamente, por ejemplo a mitad de un método muy tardado o a un miembro de la clase que se sabe que no se utlizará más adelante.

```
public void notificarClientes()
{
   Conexion conn;
   localConn = new Conexion();
   ListaCLientes clientes = buscarClientes(localConn);
   //de acá en adelante no se utilizará más la conexión.
   localConn = null;
   //acá comenzamos a enviar emails, cosa que ya no tiene nada que ver 
   //con la base de datos y es potencialmente tardado
   for (Cliente cliente : clientes) {
        notificarCliente(cliente);
    }
}
```

Pero,

## No todo es la memoria

- **Recursos**

  Hay casos concretos donde la referencia a un objeto puede estar haciendo uso de otros recursos del sistema que también son escasos, no solo de memoria. Hablamos de *handles* a recursos del sistema, tales como archivos, procesos, conexiones de bases de datos, etc.

  En casos como este, la práctica habitual es implementar la *liberación* de estos recursos en el método `release()`, que se invoca cuando ya el objeto en cuestión no será utilizado.

  Volviendo al ejemplo anterior, podría quedar algo como:

  ```
  public Cliente buscarcliente(int id)
  {
     Conexion conn;
     localConn = new Conexion();
     try {
         CLiente result = realmenteBuscarAlCliente(localConn, id);
         return result;
     } finally {
         //nos aseguramos de liberar los recursos.
         localConn.release();
     }
     //acá, al terminar el método, la variable localConn sale de 
     //contexto y eventualmente será destruida, liberando la memoria que ocupa.
  }
  ```
- **Operaciones costosas en tiempo**

  El tiempo es oro. En la informática, como en la vida, muchas veces intercambiamos una cosa por otra. Hay muchas ocasiones en que el recurso más escaso y más caro es el tiempo. Generalmente la memoria es barata en comparación con el tiempo (siempre que no hablemos de micro-dispositivos).

  En esta línea de pensamiento, establecer una conexión a una base de datos es un buen ejemplo de un proceso que en ocasiones es costoso en tiempo comparado con su tamaño en memoria. Digo esto con mucho cuidado, pues hay casos donde la licencia de acceso concurrente a la base de datos puede ser más cara que todas las anteriores, así que no lo tomes como una verdad escrita en piedra, siempre hay que evaluar.

  Siguiendo con esta línea de pensamiento, puede resultar más efectivo para una aplicación establecer la conexión, y una vez establecida, mantenerla así y re-utilizarla para hacer muchas operaciones, antes de desconectarse de la base de datos. De hecho, en la vida real, muchas aplicaciones —sobre todo servidores de aplicaciones— mantienen multiples conexiones establecidas a la base de datos en lo que se conoce como un [*Connection pool*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool).

  Otro ejemplo clásico en el que se crean objetos que se mantienen por mucho tiempo antes de su liberación, son los [*Thread pool*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) (en inglés)

## No hay recetas

Para esto no hay una receta que funcione para todo. Ni hay algo que sea absolutamente *lo mejor*, siempre dependerá de los requerimientos, el uso que se le de a las aplicaciones y del diseño que tengan.

Comment: Gracias, ha sido de gran ayuda su respuesta

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Considera marcar una respuesta como aceptada, eso ayudará a futuros navegantes a identificar cual es la respuesta que te ha servido, en este caso, para despejar tus dudas. Entiendo que puedas preferir esperar a ver si aparece otra respuesta, solo pido que no olvides, al final, marcar alguna. Si no sabes, como, te invito a hacer nuevamente el [tour]. Un saludo.